# How do a assign a firebase database value to a variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I don't have any code because this is just a theoretical idea. But would there be a way to assign a variable to a realtime database value? If so, could I get some help?

Comment: you'll need to explain a little more. What you've said is far too vague

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have the following database structure:

```
user: 123
    name: user
```

And let's say you want to get the value of `name` once and assign it as a variable and log it in the console.

And since you want to use Firebase's [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once_with_get), you'll use:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, child, get } from "firebase/database";

const dbRef = ref(getDatabase());
get(child(dbRef, `123`))
    .then((snapshot) => {
        snapshot.forEach((child) => {
            let name = child.val(); // user
            console.log(hello);
            let key = child.key; // name
            console.log(key);
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

In the above code, I access `123` and `forEach` snapshot (which in this case only one - `name`), I'll call it `child`. And `child.val()` will print `user` (aka the value of the document) and `child.key` will print `name` (aka the key of the document) and I can easily assign them to variables and use them anywhere like `console.log()`.

I've tested the code personally, but it should work as expected.

Comment: I was thinking something in reverse. Like getting the value of test without using a variable so i can get that whenever i want. Wouldn't it be something like the get() function?

Comment: @Hehefunnyboi2 You mean `data: "test"`, yeah that's possible I guess, it'll be wrote as `hello: test` in the database.

Comment: no, what I mean is using firebase's get() function. I want to get the value of "data:" whenever I want. I want to get a value from the database, assign it to a variable, and then console.log the variable. So I already have a value saved. I wan't to get that value and assign it to a variable.

Comment: @Hehefunnyboi2 [Something like this?](https://jsfiddle.net/2muza3qh/)

Comment: yes, that seems right. But one quick thing, I'm sorry to bother you but would you mind explaining what some of that code does and what everything means. I love to learn as I go and I have found that works best. I am very new to web dev. If not, no worry, sorry for your time.

Comment: @Hehefunnyboi2 You're welcome, happy to help. See my answer, I tried to explain it. Also, you should probably try the code by yourself to see if it's working as expected. And if my answer helped, don't forget to upvote and tick the grey checkmark.

Comment: Of course, tysm

Comment: One more quick question, how would I go about making variables if there is more than one piece of data in the path, for example: user: 123, name: name, email: hi@gmail.com. Or in simple terms, i am making a login system and want to check if password and email fall under the imputed username.